# Set the list of dict to the state in React

Tags: reactjs, sorting, setstate

I have a list of od dicts. It looks like this:

```
document.__moreComments = [
  { id: 2, author: '...', text: '...', date: '...' },
  { id: 1, author: '...', text: '...', date: '...' },
];
```

I want to sort my data by date and rendered it.
Firstly I want to create an object in the declaration and set it in state. Then sorting and represent changing data. I have a problem.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

var addcomments = document.__moreComments;

class AdditionalComments extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    //    this.state = addcomments

    this.state = {
      comments: addcomments.map(addcomment => [
        addcomment.id,
        addcomment.author,
        addcomment.text,
        addcomment.date
      ])
    };
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  changeMessage() {
    let sortedComments = this.state.comments;
    this.setState({
      comments: sortedComments.sort((a, b) => a.date > b.date)
    });
    console.log(this.state.comments);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>hi Eugene {this.state.comments} </h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.changeMessage()}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AdditionalComments;
```

I create dict of dict. And of course I want to know. Is it right to do what I do or I need another approach? 
Thanks. I'm a beginner.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I want to sort my data but when I create an object and use this method (sortedComments.sort((a, b) => a.date > b.date)), nothing happens. I think I made a mistake when I create an object, because I haven't opportunity to use keys in object. This is console.log after declaration comments:                                                            0: (4) [4, "Elena Builes", "Excelent!", "2017-09-11T11:30:05.919Z"]
1: (4) [3, "Germán Toro", "Splendid!", "2017-09-11T14:30:05.919Z"]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts array in-place(that means it won't return new instance of array), that's the reason your array is not getting sorted. You should try below approach:

```
changeMessage() {
    let sortedComments = [...this.state.comments].sort((a,b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))
    this.setState({
      comments: sortedComments
    }, () => {console.log(this.state.comments)});
  }
```

Comment: @zhenyachet Did above answer helped you?

Comment: It doesn't work. Mayby because I haven't any keys in my component comments... and it needs to another approach for setting this object.

Comment: can you describe the problem you are facing?

Comment: This is the data:
 [
  { id: 3, author: 'Germán Toro', text: 'Splendid!', date: '2017-09-11T14:30:05.919Z' },
  { id: 4, author: 'Elena Builes', text: 'Excelent!', date: '2017-09-11T11:30:05.919Z' },
];

I want to sort this list by date

Comment: I have updated code. This should work for sorting according to date

Comment: My code in here https://codepen.io/eloquentfish/pen/NWqBQag
No sorting

Comment: Sorry. That approach with object date is working. Thank you so much...

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept answer if it helped you.